# Creating a customized objects function (in R) that uses regular expression

Tags: regex, r

Why does not the following custom objects function work?

```
objects0 <- function(find_term) 
{
  objects(pattern=glob2rx(paste0("*",find_term,"*")))
}
txt1 <- 100
tt <- 200
> objects0('txt')
character(0)
```

But when I write

```
objects(pattern=glob2rx(paste0("*",'txt',"*")))
```

it works just fine.

Comment: It doesn't work because `txt1` doesn't exist in the function's environment, where `objects` is searching.

Comment: should it not just search `.GlobalEnv` or parent environment by defualt?

Comment: That doesn't seem like a sensible default. Searching the _current_ environment is not a surprising default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the environment where to look for objects.

Add parameter `envir=parent.frame()` to `objects` call:

```
objects0 <- function(find_term)objects(pattern=glob2rx(paste0("*",find_term,"*")), envir=parent.frame())
```

Maybe a better way is to add `envir=globalenv()` to ensure that the search is done in the global environment always.